# Containerising an application to transparently read/write files on the host filesystem

Tags: python, bash, docker

I want to containerise a Python script which reads/writes files. The script has very specific environment requirements, so I want to use Docker to make deployment easy and repeatable.

These are the command line options of the script:

```sh
% python myscript.py  --help
usage: myscript.py [-h] inputfile outputfile

positional arguments:
  inputfile      input file to read from
  outputfile     output file to write to

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
```

Here is how my Dockerfile looks so far:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Install requirements
RUN ...

# Install the script from source code
WORKDIR /src
RUN ...

# Define entrypoint to the container
WORKDIR /root
ENTRYPOINT ["python3.7", "/src/myscript/myscript.py"]
```

This is how I would like to be able to use my containerised application:

```sh
docker build -t myscript .

docker run \
  -v <some_very_clever_bind_mount> \
  myscript <input_relative_to_host_dir> <output_relative_to_host_dir>
```

I.e. I would like to be able to specify the input and output files relative to where the `docker run` command is executed on the host operating system. In other words, be fully transparent to the fact that we're dealing with a containerised application, rather than a script run on the host OS.

Can someone think of a clever way to make what I'm after possible?

Or is there another Docker design pattern that achieves my high level goal?

Any help appreciated!

PS: My inspiration were the containerised build steps in Google Cloud Build, but I'm not sure how Google achieved the binding of the build environment filesystem to make their behaviour possible.

PPS: [Dockerized executable read/write on host filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48685327/dockerized-executable-read-write-on-host-filesystem) is a similar question, but I already know that it's possible by binding volumes. The essence of my problem is how to do it in a way where the docker container is natural to interact with from the point of view of providing file paths on the host OS.

Comment: Docker containers are their own filesystem. The container and anything inside it won't know how to access anything outside the container. You'll have to do a translation of the host path to the container path - which means you have to let the script know how you've done the mounting. So you don't actuall end up achieving what you wanted to achieve. It's not worth it IMO. Just use the container path for the arguments.

Comment: Why can't you use something like a Python virtual environment?  That will be able to use normal host paths, it will still have an isolated set of package installs, and it will honor the calling user's permissions.

Comment: @DavidMaze the dependencies are not only Python packages — some of the are things like ffmpeg, etc. So I think it’s not an option unfortunately :( unless Python virtual environments allow that as well? (I would be surprised)

Comment: @rdas thanks for the comment! I’ll look into whether there is a clean way to do the translation, but I think it will be tricky as not all of the arguments are filepaths...

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand the question, so I'll post as a comment instead of an answer. You could mount your working directory (`$PWD`) to a similar path inside the container (also `$PWD`), like : `docker run -v $PWD:$PWD myscript $PWD/my-input $PWD/my-output`, or `docker run -v /my/path/on/host:/my/path/on/host myscript /my/path/on/host/input /my/path/on/host/output`. Inside the container, you will then have the same path as if you were running your script on your host. You could also bind your whole filesystem `docker run -v /:/ ...` but I **do not recommend** it though.

Comment: @norbjd that’s an interesting suggestion! Thanks! I need to get to my computer to test it a bit more, but off the top of your head — is the “$(pwd)” part needed in the script arguments? I know that “~” gets expanded to an absolute path. I wonder if the same is true of relative paths. I also suppose that relative paths outside of the host current dir would not work, ie “../somewhere/else”

Comment: You can set the working directory inside the container with `-w /path/to/my/workdir`. Once done, you can pass a relative path to your script (relative to that particular directory). For example, if your input file is located in `/path/to/input/file`, you can run : `docker run ... -w /path/to/my/workdir myscript ../../input/file <your_output>`. Does that answer your question?